# Coloring ListPlot markers using ColorFunction

Tags: plotting

Is there a way to use ColorFunction to color markers in ListPlot or DateListPlot the way it can be used in functions like Plot3D? I do know methods for doing that by generating Points or mapping styles onto the data, but I'm looking for a simpler way to do this with large data sets.

This doesn't seem to work:

```
data = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 5}, {4, 6}};

ListPlot[data, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, If[y > 4, Red, Green]]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`. Otherwise, `y` is defaulted scaled between 0 and 1.

```
data = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 5}, {4, 6}};

ListPlot[data, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, If[y>4, Red, Green]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```